# Is a video sitemap enough for SEO or should video markup schema also be used?

Tags: seo, sitemap, structured-data, video, video-sitemap

I already implemented a video sitemap, based on [Google's recommendation](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/videosearch/sitemaps). Now, I am reading about [video markups](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/video). The only information, I got on [the relationship of both approaches to each other](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/videosearch/intro), is:

> Use both on-page markup and video sitemaps. A common scenario is to use on-page markup for all of your videos and a video sitemap to tell Google about any new, time-sensitive, or hard to find videos.

Afaik, the video sitemap is more widely supported among search engine providers, e.g. [Bing seems to just start supporting JSON-LD](https://searchengineland.com/bing-confirmed-support-json-ld-formatted-schema-org-markup-293508).

Is there any reason that speaks for using video markups in addition to video sitemaps?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean with `video markup` inline microdata - than i would say `no`. Video sitemap together with JSON-LD snippet of type http://schema.org/VideoObject are in my opinion absolutely enough.

Comment: No. I mean `video markup` as described in the second link. And, this is only supported in JSON-LD. The only reason, I can think of, for using `video markup` in addition to `video sitemap` is to get Google to list a video in the search results that wasn't indexed with the help of the `video sitemap`.

Comment: Google compares current page's content with the state of its summary, like sitemap or shopping feed. And, if states are different, the page's current content is a kind of the fallback, which is taken by Google. So i would say: make your onpage JSON-LD and sitemap always up-to-date.

Comment: @user2486134: "this is only supported in JSON-LD" -- where does it say that?

Comment: @unor: In the [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/video), examples are only given for JSON-LD and "JSON-LD with AMP support". Therefore, I assume that nothing else is supported by Google.

Comment: @user2486134: Generally, Google supports all three syntaxes for their search features (JSON-LD, Microdata, RDFa). Certain features only work with some syntaxes, though, but in such a case, Google would typically state this explicitly (the absence of examples doesn’t necessary mean that it’s not supported). However, I have no experience with this video feature, so maybe they just forgot to mention that it only works with JSON-LD.